# Can't use Nvidia GeForce 310m in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, 13.04, nvidia, graphics, bumblebee

Okay so before anybody marks this as a possible duplicate or something along those lines let me say what ive worked on; I have used Bumblebee,Manually installed the drivers myself,tried a bunch of old drivers and new ones in hopes of something happening,re-installed drivers and bumblebee and done a re-installation of the OS and nothing...

Im dualbooting Ubuntu 13.04 next to Windows 7 (both are 64-bit) and the problem is that i cant seem to get my GPU running and i found that Ubuntu cant acces the gpu for some reason (this showed up while working with bumblebee in a terminal)...i have Intel HD Graphics (built in) and an Nvidia Geforce 310m (512mb)

These are my specs;

CPU; Intel Core i5
Ram; 4Gb (3.7 to be exact)
HDD; 500gb (divided equaly in half for both Operating Systems)
GPU; Nvidia Geforce 310m 512mb (as mentioned)
Computer/Laptop; Toshiba Satellite E205

:) Help is apretiated

Comment: I also have Optimus and just got my Nvidia card working. Could you try disabling Optimus in your BIOS, and setting your computer to use only discreet graphics? That way, the nvidia kernel module will see the card and load at boot time.

Comment: I dont have that option in my laptops BIOS o_o

Comment: Do you have Bumblebee installed now?

Comment: I do and have for a while now and still nothing :/ i cant even execute optirun...

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A1`. Also, why do you think that your GPU don't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have the Samsung q330 and i have the same issue, i can resolved it with this.

Open synaptic and remove all nvidia drivers and nouveaun, like so:

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia * nouvea*` or `sudo apt-get clean nvidia* nouvea*`

**Open terminal and install:**

> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`
>   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`
>   `sudo apt-get update`
>   `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic nvidia-319`
>   `sudo apt-get install bumblebee virtualgl linux-headers-generic`
>   `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`
>   `sudo reboot`

**And you can test with this command:**

`optirun glxgears -info`

If all works out you can see something like this:

- GL_RENDERER   = GeForce 310M/PCIe/SSE2
- GL_VERSION    = 3.3.0 NVIDIA 325.15
- GL_VENDOR     = NVIDIA Corporation

its run some 3D graphics and say you fps.
You can use too optimusrun glxspheres, and glxspeheres to test mxpixel/sec
Good luck