# GT 310M Graphics drivers for Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have unsuccessfully tried to get X-server working with my laptop. 
After this didn't work I tried this older post from a person with same laptop model as me (Samsung q330) [Can't use Nvidia GeForce 310m in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316811/cant-use-nvidia-geforce-310m-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Unfortunatly when I run the `optirun glxgears -info` I get this:

```
[  504.481883] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver [  504.482007] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

I am at an dead end. Unless someone can bring the "magical solution" I have to make due with the integrated i3 Graphics.

Edit:
Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` as requested by Pilot6

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c557

Kernel driver in use: i915
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [GeForce 310M] (rev ff)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
Subsystem: Wistron NeWeb Corp. Device 051a
```

Edit 2:
Output from `sudo prime-select nvidia` &

```
Info: the current alternatives in use are: ['mesa', 'mesa']
Info: selecting nvidia-346 for the nvidia profile
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-346/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-346/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
```

Output from `sudo prime-select nvidea`

```
Info: the current alternatives in use are: ['nvidia-346', 'nvidia-346']
Info: selecting nvidia-346-prime for the intel profile
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-346-prime/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-346-prime/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Pilot6 I have now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

Bumblebee does not work well in 15.04. You can switch the adapters by `nvidia-prime`.

Switching adapters is done by

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

or

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

Comment: nvidia-prime command not found is the only thing I get.

Comment: @RasmusMathiesen Please post the exact command and output TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: Like now? Not sure what else you mean

Comment: @RasmusMathiesen That's my bad. I gave you a wrong driver. See the updated answer.